# Find or search, highlight and replace all text occurrences in a in rendered HTML page in react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I am working on implementing find and replace functionality in my React project. Currently, my React app renders an HTML page using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, which contains a lots of of text. I have two input fields, one for entering the text to find in the HTML page and another for specifying the replace text. Additionally, I have two buttons one for replacing the current occurrence and another for replacing all occurrences. The UI includes pagination indicating the number of results found, along with previous and next buttons to navigate through the search results (similar to the find and replace feature in VS Code when we CTRL+F in our code).

I have successfully implemented the following functionalities:

- Finding the text specified in the find input field.
- Replacing all
  occurrences of the specified text.

Now, I need assistance or references to implement the remaining functionalities:

- Highlighting the found text in the rendered HTML.
- Redirecting to the relevant search result when the previous or next button is clicked.
- Replacing the particular text when the replace button is clicked.

I appreciate any guidance or references you can provide to help me complete these functionalities.

Adding the whole code for my component:
(Note: I removed some unnecessary parts in my code to easy understanding)

```
export const Home = () => {    
  const [HTMLContent, setHTMLContent] = useState(""); // Has html with so many text in p tags
  const [findSearchQuery, setFindSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [replaceSearchQuery, setReplaceSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [noOfResult, setNoOfResult] = useState(0);
  const [totalNoOfResults, setTotalNoOfResults] = useState(0);
  const [currentResultIndex, setCurrentResultIndex] = useState(0);

  const htmlContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);



  const handleFindReplace = () => {
    const containerRef = htmlContainerRef?.current;
    const currentContent = containerRef?.textContent;

    if (!findSearchQuery || !replaceSearchQuery) {
      alert("find text or replace text is not present");
      return;
    }

    // Update the state with the search results count and reset the current index
    setCurrentResultIndex(0);

    if (containerRef) {
      const regex = new RegExp(findSearchQuery, "gi");
      const matchCount = (currentContent?.match(regex) || []).length;
      console.log("matchCount", matchCount);
      const updatedContent = containerRef.innerHTML.replaceAll(regex, replaceSearchQuery);
      containerRef.innerHTML = updatedContent;
      setHTMLContent(updatedContent);
    }
  };

  const handleNextResult = () => {
    console.log("totalNoOfResults", totalNoOfResults);
    if (totalNoOfResults === 0) return;
    setCurrentResultIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % totalNoOfResults);
    console.log("currentResultIndex", currentResultIndex);
    // Scroll to the next occurrence
    scrollToResult();
  };

  const scrollToResult = () => {
    // scroll needs to be build
    return;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const containerRef = htmlContainerRef?.current;
    const currentContent = containerRef?.textContent;
    const regex = new RegExp(findSearchQuery, "g");
    const textOccurrences = (currentContent?.match(regex) || []).length;
    setTotalNoOfResults(textOccurrences);
  }, [findSearchQuery]);

  const handleFindOperation = (e) => {
    console.log("find operation executed");
    const searchQuery = e.target.value;
    setFindSearchQuery(searchQuery);
  };

  return (
    <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" minHeight="100vh">
      <HeaderPane></HeaderPane>
      <Box display="flex" flex="1">
        {/* left sidebar */}
        <Sidebar display="flex">
          <Box>
            <InputField
              placeholder="Find"
              icon={<Search20Filled />}
              onChange={(e) => handleFindOperation(e)}
              value={findSearchQuery}
            />
            <InputField
              placeholder="Replace with"
              onChange={(e) => setReplaceSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
              value={replaceSearchQuery}
            />
            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end">
              <Button color="surface" label="Replace" size="small" />
              <KButton
                color="surface"
                label="Replace all"
                size="small"
                onClick={handleFindReplace}
              />
            </Box>
            // finder component has a pagination like UI (ex. text says "1 / 2
            Results" and buttons with left arrow and right arrow to point the
            result )
            <Finder
              count={noOfResult}
              totalCount={totalNoOfResults}
              onRightButtonClick={handleNextResult}
            />
          </Box>
        </Sidebar>
        <ContentPane>
          <div
            ref={htmlContainerRef}
            style={{
              position: "relative",
              marginLeft: showTagPane ? "100px" : "0px",
              paddingLeft: "10px",
            }}
          >
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: HTMLContent }} />
          </div>
        </ContentPane>
      </Box>
      <FooterPane></FooterPane>
    </Box>
  );
};
```